# Getting ImportError on spyder when trying to open a DataFrame after updating pandas and numpy

Tags: python, pandas, spyder

I was trying to run some commands that needed me to update `pandas`, and then `numpy`, and so I did. Problem is now, when I try to look into a DataFrame in the variable explorer, they don't open and I get this error instead:
`ImportError: No module named 'pandas.core.internals.managers'; 'pandas.core.internals' is not a package`

Do you know what is happening?

Comment: What version of Pandas is this? I'm guessing some compatibility has been broken in the latest version.

Comment: It's '0.24.1' according to spyder

Comment: If it is the latest version, try downgrading and checking again. If that works and a re-upgrade breaks it again, I would raise on Spyder GitHub

Comment: Actually then, the reverse is probably more likely, you might need to update Spyder. Let's see if there's any existing issues.

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) Spyder is working fine with the latest Pandas, so I guess this problem probably has to do with using pip or conda-forge to update Pandas in Anaconda (although the OP didn't mention how he did it).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I solved it installing the pandas version 0.24.2

`pip install pandas==0.24.2`